# ActivityRecognition on Android Wear

Tags: wear-os, activity-recognition

I am developing Android Wear app that uses activity recognition to see if a user(office worker) have been in a still position for a certain time (if the user have been on their desk for too long), if so, it pushes notification, telling user to take a short break, and take a walk . I have followed a couple of ActivityRecognition tutorials aimed for handheld devices. After implementing code, during initial test the app on my watch does seem to recognise activities that I am undertaking with some minor issues. However, on stackoverflow I read that since android wear does not have dedicated ActivityDetection API, it will misbehave. Someone instead suggested to use accelerometer data for motion detection. On the other hand there is Google Fit API. Since I am new to android wear development I am not sure what is the right way to go. Could you please give me an advise on what is the right way to go in terms of tracking user motion, and if using ActivityRecognition for wear is reliable?﻿ Or should I try to make use of Google Fit API?

Answer (score 0):

[Google Fit API](https://developers.google.com/fit/) is commonly use to let users control their fitness data. If you want to push notification once a user is still in the same position for a certain time, I think you can use this API whenever a specific data source or data type is updated on the [fitness store](https://developers.google.com/fit/overview#the_fitness_store). Check on this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/listen-for-data).

However, I have found this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27040679/android-activity-recognition-on-wearables) regarding Android activity recognition on wearables. I guess you already checked this link and I agreed on using [accelerometer data](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html) to monitor the motion of a device.

The following code shows you how to get an instance of the default acceleration sensor:

```
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mSensor;
  ...
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: In the link to the other stackoverflow question, it said: "One way would be to use the raw accelerometer data to detect motion. It is fairly easy to detect that the device is not moving at all, to detect anything else is not trivial." does that mean no movement at all or just a slight movement e.g. if user is sitting on their desk using different hand gestures, but remaining in the same location e.g. sitting? Would it be possible using accelerometer to differentiate when using is sitting but using hand gestures, form when user is moving (e.g. walking, running)?